# Mysterious padding on top of a background image in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, background, padding

I have a background image that has about 20px or so of padding show up in IE.  It pushes the whole page down.  The mysterious bit is that I have the entire background tiled with another image that that isn't showing up in the gap.  Looks fine in firefox and elsewhere. I have margins/padding set to 0 all over,css reset code, etc.

http://circore.com/sporttours/news/

This is the css on that area in style.css but I'm guessing something elsewhere is making this wonky:

```
#content-top 
{ 
    background:url(images/mainheader.png) no-repeat;
    height:171px;
    width:690px;
    margin-left:210px;
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking the whitespace out of main_bg:

```
<div id="main_bg">
    <img src="http://circore.com/sporttours/wp-content/themes/Memoir/images/bg.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

**->**

```
<div id="main_bg"><img src="http://circore.com/sporttours/wp-content/themes/Memoir/images/bg.jpg" alt="" /></div>
```

Comment: Both of these were correct.  Thanks, would never have thought of that myself!

Answer (score 0):

this image call in your main_bg div:

src="http://circore.com/sporttours/wp-content/themes/Memoir/images/bg.jpg"

is returning a 404 error.

That gap looks like the space for the browsers broken image link icon.
Is this 0x0 image even necessary in the html?

I see it in safari as well.